# how to properly install django-import-export

Tags: django, import, export

I am trying to import excel sheets into my django database, and i managed to install django-import-export. Following this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html , I edited the settings.py to include 'import-export' but I keep getting an error that there is no module named 'import-export'.

Following this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html , I edited the settings.py to include 'import-export' but I keep getting an error that there is no module named 'import-export' when I try to run the server.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import-export'

I am also not very sure about my following steps after this.

Comment: can you show installed packages with 'pip freeze' to verify the install?

Comment: astroid==2.2.5
backports.csv==1.0.7
colorama==0.4.1
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20181111
Django==2.2.3
django-import-export==1.2.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
isort==4.3.21
jdcal==1.4.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mysqlclient==1.4.2
odfpy==1.4.0
openpyxl==2.6.2
pylint==2.3.1
pytz==2019.1
PyYAML==5.1.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
tablib==0.13.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
wrapt==1.11.2
xlrd==1.2.0
xlwt==1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a typo in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Edit your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Use `import_export` instead of `import-export`

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'import_export',
)
```

Refer the [docs](http://Edit%20your%20INSTALLED_APPS.%20Use%20import_export%20instead%20of%20'import-export')